# FIFA 23 on PS5 from the PS store as a Christmas present

Tags: ps5, fifa-23

Sorry, this is a full on “Mum hasn’t got a clue” question.

We have bought our son a PS5 for Christmas. He has no idea he is getting it. He has FIFA23 Ultimate Edition on his PS4 and whilst I know this game can’t be transferred over, I was wondering how I go about buying it from the PlayStation store without having to create an account, and if I do have to will my son be able to use it on his account? It’s on offer at the moment so was hoping to get that for Christmas too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a PSN account to purchase content from PS Store.

Then, in order to let other accounts play your downloaded contents on the same PS5, you need to enable a setting:

[image]

This is similar to the "main console" setting present on PS4.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into your PlayStation account on a son's PS4 console.
2. Choose Settings.
3. Choose Account Management.
4. Select Activate as Your Primary PS4 and confirm the choice. You might need to deactivate your own PS4 console, but don't worry, you can reactivate it.

Now player two(your son) will see all of player one's(yours) games in their library and they'll be available for download on his PS4 hard drive as well.